# Python mock return of a getattr() call

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Edit: I might be falling the XY problem trap here. Here's what I really want to [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782736/testing-return-value-of-sqlalchemy-parent-child-relationship-query).

I have the following function:

```
def foo():
  bar = funcToGetBar()
  return bar.getattr("some_attr", None)
```

In my test, I try to do:

```
mocked_bar = MagicMock()
expected_return_val = [obj1, obj2, ...]
funcToGetBar.return_value = mocked_bar  # funcToGetBar is patched

def testGetBar(self):
  assertEqual(expected_return_val, foo())
```

Now what I want to do is to provide the `expected_return_val` onto the `some_attr` attribute on the `bar` object.

I have tried using PropertyMock:

```
type(mocked_bar).getattr = PropertyMock(return_value=expected_return_value)
```

Running my test I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

If the `return_value` is set to a scalar (not a list), the result of the `getattr` call in the real function is a mock, and not the scalar I provided.

Also, I'm worried about mocking out the `getattr` method, since it is a common method that will probably be used elsewhere in my function. How can I set a list on an attribute of my mock object under test?

Comment: I didn't follow everything but I think you want `getattr(bar, "some_attr", None)`, because `gettattr` is a builtin global function, not a method that everything has.

Comment: @AlexHall, using that method signature I end up getting my MagicMock object back, not the list I was expecting. But it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, Mock's return_value isn't iterable.  To get an iterable return_value, use side_effect.

```
mocked_bar = MagicMock()
mocked_bar.side_effect = [obj1, obj2, ...]
```

edit: Documentation is located at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock

specifically:

side_effect: A function to be called whenever the Mock is called. See the side_effect attribute. Useful for raising exceptions or dynamically changing return values. The function is called with the same arguments as the mock, and unless it returns DEFAULT, the return value of this function is used as the return value.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the documentation?

Comment: @Danny_DD - added.

Comment: Using `side_effect` means that `[mocked_bar(), mocked_bar(), ...] == [obj1, obj2]`, not that `mocked_bar() == [obj1, obj2, ...]`.

Comment: For each call that you do, you will get the next item in side_effect.
---
the first mocked_bar() == obj1
---
the second mocked_bar() == obj2