# Testing return value of SQLAlchemy parent-child relationship query

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy

Say I have two models set up like so:

```
class ParentFoo(SqlBase):
  __tablename__ = "parents"

  id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
  children = relationship("ChildFoo", backref="parents")

class ChildFoo(SqlBase):
  __tablename__ = "children"

  id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

Now in a request handler, say I want to get all children entities from the database given a parent:

```
class RequestHandler():

  def get(self, parent_id):
    parent = database.query(parent_id)
    children = parent.children
    send_response(children)
```

The SQLAlchemy ORM API allows this type of query. The problem for me is when I'm writing my tests. I have a generic `RequestHandler` class that takes a `ParentFoo` and a `ChildFoo` class as arguments in the constructor. So my request handler class actually looks like this:

```
class GenericRequestHandler():

  def __init__(self, parent_class, child_class):
    self.parent_class = parent_class
    self.child_class = child_class

  def get(self, parent_id):
    parent = database.query(self.parent_class, parent_id)
    children = parent.getattr(self.child_class.__tablename__, None)
```

As long as the column name on the parent matches the `__tablename__` for the child entities, this will work. I enforce this convention. The problem is testing this.

Python's `mock` library doesn't seem to provide for return values on attribute lookups and I don't want to mock out the `getattr` function, because it's used elsewhere in my get method.

Any thoughts?

Edit 1:
Regarding my comment about attribute lookups: I can mock out a function and provide a return value.

```
mocked_function.return_value = my_desired_value
```

But how do I mock out an attribute?

```
mocked_object.attribute_of_interest = my_desired_value
```

Edit 2:
In my tests, I provide `MagicMock` objects to the constructor for the parent and child classes, and I set a `MagicMock` object to be returned by the call to `database.query`:

```
parent_class_mock = MagicMock()
child_class_mock = MagicMock()
parent_entity = MagicMock()
type(parent_entity).getattr = PropertyMock(return_value=[child_entity])
database.query.return_value = parent_entity

class ConcreteRequestHandler(GenericRequestHandler):
  def __init__(self, parent_class, child_class):
    super(ConcreteRequestHandler, self).__init__(parent_class, child_class)
```

As you can see, I tried to use `mock`'s `PropertyMock` to set an attribute. When I ran the test, I got an error saying `'list' object not callable`. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781464/python-mock-return-of-a-getattr-call) SO question I asked related to this.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "Python's `mock` library doesn't seem to provide for return values on attribute lookups"? Which classes are you mocking?

Comment: @univerio See my edit.

Comment: You can mock attributes like that just fine. What problems are you running into?

Comment: @univerio please see my edit. I think the problem is that I have to use getattr() to access the property on my parent entity. Since in the test, this is a mock object, I just end up getting another mock object from the call.

Comment: You're using `PropertyMock`. That means the expression `parent_entity.getattr` has value `[child_entity]`. You want to set `parent_entity.getattr.return_value = [child_entity]`, which means `parent_entity.getattr(...)` has value `[child_entity]`. By the way, having a `.getattr` method on a class is really weird when there's a `getattr` built-in.

Comment: I'm using getattr because the attribute holding the children is dynamically set at runtime. It depends on the child class. I cannot know what the attribute name is, but I know it will be the the name of the children table.

Comment: There is **only** runtime in Python (not strictly true in the technical sense, but practically true). Attributes are not set at any other time. Even if it's set dynamically, even if it depends on the child class's table name, as long as you're not applying some transformation to the name in your `.getattr` method, you can use the [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in instead.